# php multidimensional array remove element by using 1 of the column value

Tags: php

I look through some of the posts in SOF, its abit confusing for me. Hence I post a question here.

```
$cars[] =[1,"Volvo",22,18,99];
$cars[] =[2,"BMW",15,13,99];
$cars[] =[3,"Saab",5,2,99];
$cars[] =[4,"Benz ",17,15,99];

echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="10">';
echo '<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Total</th></tr>';
foreach ($cars as $key => $row) {
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($row as $key2 => $val) {

   echo "<th>";
   echo $cars[$key][$key2]." ";
   echo "</th>";

}
echo "</tr>";

}
echo '</table>';
```

The above coding is to display all the elements in multi array. If i want to remove one of the element, i can use 2 methods:

```
unset($cars[3][0],$cars[3][1],$cars[3][2],$cars[3][3],$cars[3][4]); 

unset($cars[3]);
```

so the last row( [4,"Benz ",17,15,99] ) will be deleted.

**What if I want to remove the element by using 1st value of that element?**

**For example, "4" -> array position -> $cars[3][0] .**

Basically, I can only use the 1st column value of each element as an ID to remove the whole element.

May I know how to do that?

[image]

Comment: The first unset is pointless. unsetting `$cars[3]` will remove the array entry and any sub-array values present. you can't unset by value, but you CAN search the array for that value, get the key for the entry that contains the value, then unset using that key.

Comment: Yup, the 1st unset is for demo purpose. Basically,  I am doing a add to cart function. I can only use the product ID as reference to delete the whole element. For your suggestion, any demo code? thx.

Comment: if it's a cart, then use the product ID as a cart key. `$cart[4] = array('Benz', ...)`. then you don't need to find the key, because you've already got it.

Comment: I understand what you mean. But for the coding part, I not sure, its my first time doing this. Can you show a demo ?